How to avoid accumulation of batch outputs in GPU memory during model.predict()
I am using tf.data.dataset as an input to my model.
I wish to use model.predict() while preventing results of batches from being accumulated in GPU memory. That is, I want to use model.predict() and make sure that when the forward pass for a batch is done, the output for that batch is fetched from the GPU to CPU memory and the corresponding GPU memory for the output of the batch is released.
I have an image to image translation model.
Both the input and output image have the same dimension.
My dataset is huge and can not fit in the GPU memory at once.
So I define my dataset as tf.data.Dataset and use batching on it. This makes sure that data is fetched to the GPU one batch at a time.
But the problem is: the outputs of batches are accumulated in the GPU memory till the time the full dataset finishes and then the whole output is fetched from GPU -> CPU memory. This accumulating outputs in the GPU memory causes the GPU to go out of memory very quickly.
I currently solve this by manually batching my dataset into batches that are small enough to fit inside GPU memory. Then I iterate over my dataset manually using a for loop and call model.predict() on each batch, fetch result of each batch from GPU -> CPU manually.
But the problem with this approach is: I do not know how to prefetch data for the next batch to the GPU while the current batch is being processed in the GPU. This causes GPU idling where the GPU is idle during the time the new batch to be processed is being fetched from CPU->GPU memory.
What is the best way to achieve this?
Any help would be appreciated!
